# calculate values on basis of text box entry

Tags: php, jquery

i have one row of text boxes which is generated with php loop and mysql id.

```
     <input class="text_field1" id="<?php echo $i ?>" name="q_<?php echo $row['pid']; ?>"
 type="text" style="width:150px" />
            <input  disabled="disabled" class="text_fieldD" id="p_<?php echo $row['pid'];
 ?>" name="p_<?php echo $row['pid']; ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['pprice'] ?>" />

    <input  disabled="disabled" class="text_fieldD" id="t_<?php echo $row['pid']; ?>"
 name="t_<?php echo $row['pid']; ?>" type="text" />
```

what i want is

when i enter any value in text box with class text_field1, i want to calculate total in text box name t_.... (qty * price ,p_....)

i try this code its works little bit but not all i want , my JQUERY code is

```
 $('.text_field1').bind("focus blur change keyup", function(){

        var $el = $(this);
        var numPallets =IsNumeric1($el.val());


        });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work. I only binded it to keyup in this example:

```
$('.text_field1').keyup(function() {
    var pid = $(this).attr("name").split("_")[1]; // row pid
    var q = $(this).val() * 1;
    var p = $("#p_"+pid).val() * 1;
    $("#t_"+pid).val(q * p);
});
```